# Any alternative text labels for a "Race/Ethnicity" dropdown?

Tags: forms, copywriting, dropdown, labels, labeling

The phrase 'Race/Ethnicity' or "Race/Ethnic Origin" is used throughout various data reporting.  It just looks so odd with a '/' slash.  Any alternatives?  Here are a few examples of the slash in 'real life'

- [Cancer.gov](http://surveillance.cancer.gov/statistics/types/race_ethnic.html)
- [New York State School Report Cards](https://reportcards.nysed.gov/files/2009-10/AOR-2010-480404020000.pdf).

Comment: Why not just use one or the other if you don't like that slash? "Ethnic origin", though, it probably more appropriate since race is not really a well-defined construct.

Comment: I think this rather belongs to [English Langusage & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @brian, consider rephrasing the question to ask if there is a better label for web forms or reports. The way you have it now does point to a question of English Usage.

Comment: Agree, it's more of an English Language & Usage question, but the mods on that site aren't interested in having it migrated. Unless you have data showing that it's significant problem, I don't think it's worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to be clever can sometimes be confusing.

If people are conditioned to see race, why break the convention?

Deferring to the Census Bureau, and how they present race:

http://2010.census.gov/2010census/popmap/ipmtext.php?fl=24

Comment: For our certified emr, we had to list Ethnicity and Race separately, using those exact census descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Ethnicity is the proper term. But, to be perfectly honest, many people don't know what 'Ethnicity' means. Race is a far more common (if less accurate) word used to describe this. Combining the two words reaches the broadest audience, despite it's clunky nature.